# Determining linear independence of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was watching lecture today and we were trying to figure out if three vectors were linearly independent. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw8r5.png) is how my professor created the matrix. He made the vectors the rows of the matrix, but I thought that the vectors were supposed to be the columns? Can anyone explain why it was arranged like this? Thank you.

Comment: No, row vectors. We want to show that he three row vectors of this matrix are linearly independent. You could also look at the four column vectors, but that's another question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde how do I know when to make the vectors columns and when to make them rows?

Comment: For a matrix it doesn't matter, because the column rank is equal to the  row rank. Passing to the transpose matrix, you can always use row reduction. What you have in mind perhaps, is the matrix $A$ of a linear map $f$, where the images $f(e_i)$ under basis vectors are the *columns* of the associated matrix. So $f(x)=Ax$.

Answer (score 0):

Given vectors $v_1,…,v_n$ we can turn them into a matrix $A=(v_1\mid … \mid v_n)$ (in the way you suggested, ie. by letting the columns be given by the vectors. Moreover there is the transpose $A^T$ of $A$, in which the rows are given by the vectors.

Now (assuming we have less vectors than the dimension of the surrounding vector space) the vectors are linear independent if and only if $A$ has full rank if and only if $A^T$ has full rank. The last equivalence holds, since $\operatorname{rank} A = \operatorname{rank} A^T$.

Now to the question, why your professor chose to use $A^T$. I would bet that the way you were taught the Gauß-algorithm is to use row-operations. You might also know about column operations, but since mixing them up is a bad thing and column operations are mere row operations on the transpose, it is maybe better to stick with one of them.

Now since $\operatorname{rank} A = \operatorname{rank} A^T$ we might use row operations on either of $A$ or $A^T$ to determine the rank. But $A^T$ still is the better choice:

Suppose you not only want to find out if vectors are linear independent, but want to find a basis of the subspace generated by them. You would normally do this by successively writing one of the vectors as linear combination of the others until this doesn’t work anymore. Now note that doing row operations on a matrix is nothing but writing down linear combinations of the rows. So instead of working with linear combinations of the vectors manually, we might as well use the Gauß-algorithm (row operations) on our matrix $A^T$.

Of cause we could also use column operations on $A$, but note that row operations on $A$ do nothing of value here, so using $A$ has a high risk of doing the wrong thing, if one is used to row-operations.